# issues with rock paper scissor game in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

its my first day on a coding and started of on a rock paper scissor game , i get this error how can i fix this

input:

```
import random


def get_choices():
    player_choice = (input('Enter a choice (Rock , Paper , Scissors)'))
    c_choices = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']
    computer_choice = random.choice(c_choices)
    choices = {'player': player_choice, 'computer': computer_choice}
    return choices


def check_win(player,computer):
    print(f"You chose {player},computer chose {computer}")
    if player == computer:
        return "its a tie!"
    elif player== 'rock':
        if computer=='scissors':
            return "ROCK SMASHES SCISSORS!, YOU WIN!"
        else:
            return "PAPER COVERS ROCK!, YOU LOSE!"

    elif player== 'paper':
        if computer=='rock':
            return "PAPER COVERS ROCK, YOU WIN!"
        else:
            return "SCISSOR CUTS PAPER!, YOU LOSE!"

    elif player == 'scissors':
        if computer == 'paper':
            return "SCISSORS CUTS PAPER!, YOU WIN!"
        else:
            return "ROCK SMASHES SCISSORS!, YOU LOSE!"

choices = get_choices()
result = check_win(choices['player'], choices['computer'])
print(result)
```

output

[It should have been a tie as directed on line 13/14](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvfGC.png)

expected a tie result

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 3):

The strings in `c_choices` are capitalized.

And in `def check_win()` you compare them against lowercase strings.

use:

```
c_choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
```

instead of:

```
c_choices = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']
```